# 'This page doesn't work' in articles & items

Tags: joomla-3.x, error-handling

A strange issue occurred in my site https://myagiaparaskevi.gr/ suddenly. I've done no changes except publishing new articles. Every time I try to visit an article I get 'This page doesn't work'. After 3 or 4 times refreshing it finally opens. The same with some menu items. Note that not all of them have this behaviour. Any ideas?

EDIT: Problem solved: it was caused by an article with bad format (not formatted/filtered text)...

Comment: You should post your solution/EDIT  as the answer and then accept the answer to show you have resolved you issue. It helps when someone else might find your question in researching their own issue to see your question is resolved/accepted